# Keep focus on Ember.TextField

Tags: javascript, ember.js, focus

In my Ember.js application I have a search text field like this:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="search" action="doSearch" autofocus="autofocus"}}
<button {{action "doSearch"}} type="button">Hledat</button>
```

and a controller like the following:

```
App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    queryParams: ['keywords'],
    keywords: [],

    search: "",

    actions: {
        doSearch: function() {
            var tokens = this.get('search').split(' ');
            this.set('keywords', tokens);
            this.set('search', '');
        }
    }
});
```

What I need is that this text field keeps focus even after the button has been pushed or enter key pressed.

What's the correct way to achieve that? I guess I'll need to set focus back to the input box in the doSearch method somehow. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Communication between the controller and view layer can be achieve in a clean way using [Ember.Evented](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html)

Here we go

**Your template :**

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="search" class="search-field" action="doSearch" autofocus="autofocus"}}
<button {{action "doSearch"}} type="button">Hledat</button>
```

**Your controller :**

```
App.BooksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(Ember.Evented, {

    queryParams: ['keywords'],
    keywords: [],

    search: "",

    actions: {
        doSearch: function() {
            var tokens = this.get('search').split(' ');
            this.set('keywords', tokens);
            this.set('search', '');
            this.trigger('search');
        }
    }
});
```

**And your view :**

```
App.BooksView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.get('controller').on('search', function() {
            $('.search-field').focus();
        });
        this._super();
    }
});
```

It could be even better to access the text field  by scoping the view

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.get('controller').on('search', function() {
        this.$().find('.search-field').focus();
    }.bind(this);
    this._super();
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the 'search' handler function is triggered n times when you hit the search button for the n-th time. That does not seem to be correct. Is that right?

Comment: I would try removing action="doSearch" from your field in your template. I kept it because I didn't know if it were used elsewhere.

Comment: The action="doSearch" is there to ensure that the action is triggered when you enter some keywords into the inputbox and just hit enter (instead of pressing the button). Even when removed, the suspicious n-fold trigger is still happening.